# Find the second largest value rowwise with dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr

### Problem:

I am working with wages data and I want to flag outliers as possible measurement errors. For doing so, I am combining two criteria:

1. To receive more than twice the value of the 99th percentile of wages within a given year, relative to the whole distribution of wages on my dataset (comparison criteria between persons, within year)
2. To receive more than twice the value of the second highest wage within a same person, across years. That is an intra-individual criteria (comparison criteria within person, between years).

I accomplished to code the first criteria, but I am having some trouble with coding the second one.

My data is in the wide format. Perhaps the solution to my problem can be easier achieved by reshaping the data to the long format, but as I am working in a multi-author project, if I use this solution I need to reshape it back to the wide format again.

### Data example:

Below, I provide some rows of my data with cases that already met the first criteria:

```
df <- structure(list(
    wage_2010 = c(120408.54, 11234.67, 19918.64, NA, 66006.32, 40581.36, 344587.84, 331970.28, NA, 161351.45, NA, 115310.68, 323336.27, 9681.69, NA, 682324.53, 43764.76, 134023.61, 78195.16, 141231.5, 48163.23, 71259.66, 73858.65, 57737.6, NA, 182837.23), wage_2011 = c(413419.86, 24343.04, 36349.02, NA, 99238.53, 18890.34, 129921.58, 108714.29, NA, 169289.89, 36158.73, 129543.51, 130791.99, 13872.76, 4479.58, 222327.52, 826239.14, 48892.78, 78506.06, 111569.8, 653239.41, 813158.54, 72960.17,     80193.15, NA, 209796.19), wage_2012 = c(136750.86, 77386.62, 177528.17, 86512.48, 375958.76, 20302.29, 145373.42, 91071.64, 95612.23, 176866.72, 85244.44, 225698.7, 181093.52, 162585.23, 147918.83, 254057.11, 72845.46, 86001.31, 80958.22, 105629.12, 77723.77, 115217.74, 68959.04, 111843.87, 85180.26, 261942.95    ), 
wage_2013 = c(137993.48, 104584.84, 239822.37, 95688.8, 251573.14, 21361.93, 142771.58, 92244.51, 111058.93, 208013.94, 111326.07, 254276.36, 193663.33, 225404.84, 84135.55, 259772.16, 100031.38, 100231.81, 824271.38, 107336.19, 95292.2, 217071.19, 125665.58, 74513.66, 116227.01, 245161.73), wage_2014 = c(134914.8, 527180.87, 284218.4, 112332.41, 189337.74, 23246.46, 144070.09, 92805.77, 114123.3, 251389.07, 235863.98, 285511.12, 192950.23, 205364.45, 292988.3, 318408.56, 86255.91, 497960.18, 85467.13, 152987.99, 145663.31, 242682.93, 184123.01, 107423.03, 132046.43, 248928.89), wage_2015 = c(168812.65, 145961.09, 280556.86, 256268.69, 144549.45, 23997.1, 130253.75, NA, 115522.88,     241031.91, 243697.87, 424135.76, 15927.33, 213203.96, 225118.19, 298042.59, 77749.09, 151336.85, 88596.38, 121741.45, 34054.26, 206284.71, 335127.7, 201891.17, 189409.04, 246440.69), 
wage_2016 = c(160742.14, 129892.09, 251333.29, 137192.73, 166127.1, 537611.12, 139350.84, NA, 115395.21, 243154.02, 234685.36, 903334.7, NA, 205664.08, 695079.91, 33771.37, 100938.19, 138864.28, 58658.4, 98576.95, NA, 144613.53, 430393.04, 217989.1, 229369.56, 600079.86), wage_2017 = c(175932.3, 138128.41, 584536.47, 143506.22, 61674.63, 1442.8, 126084.46, NA, 575771.83, 586909.69, 372954.89, 701815.37, NA, 402347.33, 93873.2, NA, 96792.96, 172908.08, 89006.92, 631645.41, NA, 72183.55, 579455.71, 294539.56, 353615.43, 151327.43), wage_2018 = c(146111.42, 149313.9, 627679.77, 850182.4, 72654.62, 9129.35, 41544.24, NA, 248020.12, 334280.68, 611781.99, 597465.2, NA, 535628.5, 63369.44, NA, 93710.71, 146769.63, 100736.71, 108022.87, NA, 79019.43, 772012.47, 549097.81, 504183.59, 99129.6), 
outlier_2010 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), outlier_2011 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), outlier_2012 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), outlier_2013 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), outlier_2014 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), outlier_2015 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), outlier_2016 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), outlier_2017 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),     outlier_2018 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)), 
groups = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of",     "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have averages anual wages from 2010 to 2018, that is, 9 points in time. However, it seems to be hard to use a solution with the `quantile` function, because of possible missing values for some individuals in some years.

### What I have tried:

So far I am using a median function within the dplyer approach. I flag as an outlier (possible error) if, in one given year, the individual receives more than twice the median of what he received across the years:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(
      median_wage = median(c(wage_2010, wage_2011, wage_2012, wage_2013, wage_2014, wage_2015, wage_2016, wage_2017, wage_2018), na.rm=T)) %>%
    mutate(
      individual_threshold = median_wage * 2,
   ) %>%
   mutate(
      outlier_2010 = case_when (wage_2010 > individual_threshold ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
      outlier_2011 = case_when (wage_2011 > individual_threshold ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
      outlier_2012 = case_when (wage_2012 > individual_threshold ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
      outlier_2013 = case_when (wage_2013 > individual_threshold ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
      outlier_2014 = case_when (wage_2014 > individual_threshold ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
      outlier_2015 = case_when (wage_2015 > individual_threshold ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
      outlier_2016 = case_when (wage_2016 > individual_threshold ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
      outlier_2017 = case_when (wage_2017 > individual_threshold ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
      outlier_2018 = case_when (wage_2018 > individual_threshold ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))
```

However, when I inspect the data, I see that I am coding as outlier possible legitimate wages. For example, in the third row/person of my data, I am flagging as outliers wages in 2017 and 2018. However, as we can see, there is a pattern of increase in this person's wage. Although he receives more than twice his median wage in these years, probably that is not a mistake, as the increase was recorded in two years in a row.

In the forth row, however, the 2018 wage is more likely to be wrongly reported, since there is not a similar wage to that one for the same person. In 2018 year, that person wage grew more than 4 times than it was ever before (and also became more than twice the 99th percentile of the whole distribution).

### Summing up:

I want to write a code to analyse 9 variables for every individual (or rowwise): wage_2010-2018, and compare the highest value to the second highest value. If the highest value is more than twice the size of the second highest value, I flag it as a possible measurement error. Preferably within `dplyr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do this with a helper function.

```
library(dplyr)

compare_2nd_highest <- function(x) {
  #Sort the wages in descending order
  x1 <- sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)
  #Is the highest value more than double of second highest value
  x1[1] > (x1[2] * 2)
}

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(is_outlier = compare_2nd_highest(c_across(starts_with('wage')))) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Wow, many thanks! I am not sure that I understand it, but it worked indeed to flag the rows as outliers. Just one think: is it possible to identify which year has the outlier (which year has the highest value) in a simple way? I mean, instead of writing down all possible comparisons between pairs of years. I tried to do it by creating different dummy variables for every year, etc.

Comment: In the same pipe after `is_outlier` you can add `highest_year = which.max(c_across(starts_with('wage'))))` where 1 would be the 1st year i.e 2010, 2 would be 2nd year 2011 and so on.